# End Point URL Error in HTTP Class?

Tags: apex, api, rest, httprequest, http

I have a 3rd Party Endpoint Url Which I Paste in browser Address bar I can see the XML Data.

But the same Endpoint URL , I invoke via Apex Class (Http Call) I will get a Error Message From the System saying I don't have the Permission to access the Data.

There is No Error in Apex Class.

I checked with 3rd Party Developers..they are saying they have blocked certain IP of Amazon's Server. That might cause the Issue..

What is the Solution..

Comment: you may have to add SF ip's in to whitelist.
Check this link for SF ip ranges.
https://help.salesforce.com/apex/HTViewSolution?id=000003652

Comment: @erkançipil But 3rd Party has to Whitelist the Salesforce IP.?

Comment: yes, @user40138

Comment: @erkançipil I am Not sure whether they can do this..Is there any other ways

Answer (score 0):

At one point of time, I had a similar issue of HTTP/HTTPs while using within the Salesforce environment and it was painful at some point of time.

From my experience and what @erkan has mentioned, I can suggest to try this:

1. White listing the IP address if a third party URL is a static one.
2. Hard code the URL with `https` if its used anywhere and try.